# Should someone be an author if they helped understanding a concept?

Tags: authorship

I am writing a paper. I have performed the experiments and I also have the results. However, there is a section in my paper where I have to explain my observation upon which the whole idea is based. To ensure that I explain my observation correctly, I want help from a professor. I will be basically asking him questions along the line of: ‘why does this happen?’.

Before asking such questions, shall I inform him that I’m writing a paper and need help in explaining something?
I’ll definitely thank him in the acknowledgement section but is it required to add him as an author?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> To ensure that I explain my observation correctly, I want help from a professor. I will be basically asking him questions along the line of: ‘why does this happen?’.

Whether this merits coauthorship depends on whether the professor is making a significant intellectual contribution.  If you are just getting straightforward explanations of well-known theory (which you need because you are an experimentalist, not a theorist), then there's no need for more than an acknowledgment.  On the other hand, if nobody knows why these things happen and the theorist comes up with a novel explanation for your data, then coauthorship sounds appropriate.  There may also be intermediate cases, such as theory that is relatively well known but requires some calculation to apply to your case, in which case you would need to discuss whether coauthorship makes sense.

> Before asking such questions, shall I inform him that I’m writing a paper and need help in explaining something?

Yes, certainly.  If you get only quick answers that do not seem to involve much effort, then you should mention the paper but there's probably no need to discuss coauthorship.  If you get answers that seem to involve serious effort, then you should discuss coauthorship.  (Discussing it doesn't necessarily mean he will be a coauthor.  Rather, you just need to be careful to make sure there are no misunderstandings.)

Answer (score 5):

They might merit a "thanks" acknowledgement, but probably not being credited with *doing* (a substantial part of) the work.

Answer (score 2):

The standards for coauthorship vary by discipline, but basically yes, you should probably mention that you are writing a paper before you ask your question, so you can discuss authorship up front as well.

I'm not sure though why you are worried about having a professor as a coauthor.  It's well established that papers with better known authors, or even authors from better known institutions, are more likely to be read and therefore cited.

I am a professor, and I personally tend to be generous with coauthorship.  If I think that someone has made a substantial contribution, or might make one, I tell them that I wouldn't mind if they were a coauthor.  Usually people don't take me up on that, and I just acknowledge them. Sometimes they decide they have made a substantial contribution and want their name on it, which is fine by me.

It also depends where you are publishing.  Some journals *require* that you say what the contributions of the authors are, so there's no problem with saying X did almost all the work, Y had one cunning idea.  You can also just say that in the acknowledgements if there's no other place to say it, but be careful to do it tactfully if you do it at all.

In general, I think it's better not to stress about authorship so long as you write enough papers with enough different people.  If you always write with one famous person, there's a chance they will get all the credit. But if you write with a number of combinations of authors, or if you establish a reputation through conference talks or social media, then it will be clear what part of the voice in your papers is your own.